# Meaning of function $f(x) = [x]$

Tags: functions, special-functions, graphing-functions

What does the function $f (x) = [x]$ mean?  How is it different from least and greatest integer function ?

Comment: It is possible that it is the _rounding function_ (closest integer), which is "between" the least and greatest integer functions. But without more context it's difficult to say.

Comment: I've only seen this notation used for the greatest integer ("floor") function, never for "nearest integer". But I will quickly admit that it is often appropriated and re-defined by authors to have some specific meaning unrelated to the classic usage, so anything is possible. Still, it is usually synonymous with $\lfloor x \rfloor$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$, so $[x]\leq x <[x] + 1$.

Comment: @MPW The comments section is "*to ask for more information or to suggest improvements*." Please avoid answering questions in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation): Carl Friedrich Gauss introduced the square bracket notation $[x]$ for the [floor function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html) in his third proof of quadratic reciprocity (1808).

The floor function rounds any non-integer down to the nearest integer, e.g. $\lfloor 1.1 \rfloor = \lfloor 1.9 \rfloor = 1$.

Comment: You maybe right it may be similar to least integer function but It seems similar to that but it was different in my textbook. It wasnt given properly.

Comment: @user132316 Perhaps you could give some context then...

Comment: I think you're right. I got it. Thanks Fly by Night.

Comment: @user132316 I'm glad I could help. Please up vote posts that you found useful.